# Is it possible to disable routes in Laravel Passport?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using Passport password grant, I don't need any other functionality, so I need to disable routes that are not related to password grant.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: use Passport::ignoreRoutes(); add it in register method of Auth or AppServiceProvider

Answer (score 22):

I was wondering this too and found that `Passport::routes()` takes an optional callback. If a callback is not set, then all routes get registered.

To set individual routes for each auth type modify the following code for your use in your `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
Passport::routes(function ($router) {
    $router->forAuthorization();
    $router->forAccessTokens();
    $router->forTransientTokens();
    $router->forClients();
    $router->forPersonalAccessTokens();
});
```

Comment: and it helps IDEs work better
use Laravel\Passport\RouteRegistrar;(RouteRegistrar $router)